# Clickable area bigger displayed area of search bar

Tags: css

I have a search bar that that extends when clicked on, i want to it to look exactly as it does now but the clickable area should be bigger then the visible one. I don´t know how to do this in CSS, the examples i have tried are using padding witch dosent work for me.

Images below is the extended version. 
[Extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I47UT.png) 
Next Image displays the non extended search bar. I added a blue line for the clickable width of the current bar, and a red line for the clickable width i want. 
[Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG8b7.png)

Here is my current CSS code:

```
#search {

}

#search input[type="text"] {
  background: url(../images/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 50% #f5f5f5;
  border: 0 none;

  color: #d7d7d7;
  width:10px;
  padding: 6px 16px 6px 25px;

  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;


  cursor: pointer;
}

#search input[type="text"]:focus {
  background: url(../images/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 50% #EEEEEE;
  color: #6a6f75;
  width: 101%;

  text-align: center;

  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;

  cursor: text;

  outline:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for trying helping me improve my question writing, I see i have a lot of code i don´t need to upload here, but is there anything else you see anything else that needs improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

padding is the best way to do this, if padding is upsetting other elements around the search bar, try positioning it `absolute`